# No browsers version found for Chrome

Tags: python, user-agent, scrape

I was using code which I took from internet for scraping amazon. I got first error of 'Maximum amount of retry reached' I read that need to modify useragent credentials in some places. I modified to ;

```
ua = UserAgent(use_cache_server=False,verify_ssl=False)
uag_random = ua.random

header = {
    'User-Agent': ua.chrome,
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}
```

And now, it gives an error `No browsers version found for Chrome` I have no idea how to fix?

EDIT
As I got into error in `util.py` it searches for browsers. And cannot find `chromedriver.exe` file ( I thought similarity with selenium webdriver) . And as code is from internet, I could not find where to put useragent fake to search for browser.

```
for browser in browsers_iter:
    if 'more' in browser.group(1).lower():
        continue

    browsers.append(browser.group(1))
```

EDIT2: I am trying to guess that `request` library get method tries to reach browser but is unable. The error is due that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the docs again because there are no ua.random.chrome
so if you want its random for google chrome you could try this code

```
ua = UserAgent(use_cache_server=False,verify_ssl=False)

header = {
    'User-Agent': ua['google chrome'],
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}
```

Comment: same error gives `fake_useragent.errors.FakeUserAgentError: No browsers version found for Chrome`